# Azure cosmosdb reservation

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I don't understand the sentence "A reservation discount is applied to provisioned throughput in terms of request units per second (RU/s) on an hour-by-hour basis", I needed 70,000 RU but for testing I purchased 20,000 RU as a reservation, now I already know that RUs will used 100% and thats what I want. But when the day starts it shows me 50% usage, but whole week % is 100%, I don't understand like how is distribution of RUs are done. What does this hour-by-hour mean.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1j3y.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRqS0.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer support (billing) question, not a programming question.

Comment: It's a very important question as cost optimisation is equally required from coding and Infra wise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. Reservation discount for Cosmos DB is provided on Provisioned throughput. RUs are assigned to the application on a per-second basis in increments of 100 RUs per second and it reaches to the limit on hourly basis according to the reservation. Hence when you see that the RUs are utilized by 50% that means, half of the RUs are provisioned on the minutes that are consumed.

***Note:*** A reservation discount is "use-it-or-lose-it". So, if you don't have matching resources for any hour, then you lose a reservation quantity for that hour. You can't carry forward unused reserved hours.